# Line break will count as a sentence in python

Tags: python, nlp

I am working with python for NLP. But I got a problem when i am using any text without any punctuation. But sentences come one after another line if I could not pick one line from the file through sent_tokenizer cause it works with the fullstop(.) punctuation. If anyone know the solution how to pick lines from a text without punctuation, It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Can you please provide more information? An example of what you're trying to achieve would be nice, in addition to full package information -- for example, I believe you're referring to nltk, not "python for NLP". The specifics will help us find you an answer within the tools that you're currently using!

Comment: yes, i am referring actually nltk. A paragraph where are no punctuation all the lines are separated by line break. I want to work with a specific line from the whole paragraph.

Comment: from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
 from nltk.corpus import state_union
  text=state_union.raw('some.text')
   words = ['work','life']
   sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
   for sentence in sentences:
     if (all(map(lambda word: word in sentence, words))):
        print (sentence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [str.split(sep,[maxsplit])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method, by selecting the correct separator you should be able to do what you want.
**str.splitlines([keepends])** can be useful for you too I guess.